# Openflow-based Switch Action set

Tags: cisco, ip, sdn, openflow

Based on SDN, data plane's main function is to store and forward packets based on controller's instructions (in the form of flow rules). While I was reading [OpenFlow Specification v5.1](https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-switch-v1.5.1.pdf), I came across to **Set-field** Action set which can modify the packet header. My question is: Can OpenFlow-based Switch go further than just forwarding to modify the packet header such as changing the IP address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

To be more precise, the openflow protocol defines the set-field action, but it depends on the switch implementation whether or not it supports this, and which fields can be modified if it does.

E.g. [this doc](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus/openflow/b_openflow_agent_nxos_n3kn9k/b_openflow_native_agent_nxos_7x_chapter_01.html) mentions that the openflow agent on Cisco NXOS switches support (among others) following actions:

> - Rewrite source MAC address (SMAC) Supported for the Ethertype values    0x0800 or 0x86DD (IP) only
> - Rewrite destination MAC address (DMAC)    Supported for the Ethertype values 0x0800 or 0x86DD (IP) only
> - Rewrite VLAN ID Supported for the Ethertype values 0x0800 or 0x86DD (IP) only
> - Strip VLAN (Supported for the Ethertype values 0x0800 or 0x86DD (IP)    only)
>
> Note      Rewrite DMAC and Rewrite SMAC actions must be specified
>   together.